# How to add in relation table using Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-5

I have a problem and I hope you can help me to solve it, I want to add an `Order` in to my database, this is ok.

But I want to add some informations into a relation table and it doesn't work, it said that I can't make conversion or something like that, here's my code, hope you can understand it :

P.S. the Items property is to add into the relation table `Order_Items` and the error is at the line "`ord.Items.Add(detail);`"

```
List<OrdItemDisplay> detail = new List<OrdItemDisplay>();

public void AddItems(OrdItemDisplay it)
{
    foreach (var i in detail)
    {
        if (i.ProductName == it.ProductName && i.ItemID == it.ItemID)
            detail.Add(it);
    }
}

//Inscrit dans les tables les informations
private void btnPasserCommande_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Order ord = new Order();
        OrdItemDisplay ordDet = (OrdItemDisplay)gridNewOrder.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
        AddItems(ordDet);

        ord.SupplierID = cboSuppliers.SelectedIndex + 1;
        if(Valider_Valeurs() == false)
        {
            return;
        }
        ord.Date = dtOrder.Value;
        ord.Received = tglRecue.Checked;
        db.Orders.Add(ord);
        ord.Items.Add(detail);
        db.SaveChanges();

        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Commande effectuée", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        gridNewOrder.Columns[0].Name = "Nom du jeu";
        gridNewOrder.Columns[1].Name = "Qté";
        gridNewOrder.Columns[2].Name = "Prix";
        gridNewOrder.Columns[3].Name = "Fournisseur";
        gridNewOrder.Columns[4].Name = "Date";
        gridNewOrder.Columns[5].Name = "Réception";

        string[] rows = new string[] { gridRech.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), numQte.Value.ToString(), txtPrix.Text, cboSuppliers.SelectedIndex.ToString(), dtOrder.Value.ToString(), tglRecue.Checked.ToString() };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MetroMessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Erreur(s)", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: check [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) out

Comment: there's no MVC in my project, it's c# winforms, I don't know why you send me this link?

Comment: i sent you this link so you can take a look at entity framework code-first migration example. it doesn't matter what you use for your front end.

Comment: btw, instead of "it said that I can't make conversion or something like that", it's very helpful to post the *actual* exception message that you get.